# I am getting fatal error when i run my code OpenCV code using OpenMP(C/C++)

Tags: c, opencv, openmp

I want to parallelize the execution of this program, but when i run this,i got a fatal error. OpenCV parallelization with OpenMP using C.Your Help will be appreciated. I am newbee to OpenMP and OpenCV.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <cvaux.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int no_of_frames = 0,i,j;
    int fps = 0;
    int mid_frame = 0;
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromFile("/home/nagaraj/ImageVideo/tunnel.avi");
    CvCapture* captureNew = cvCaptureFromFile("/home/nagaraj/ImageVideo/tunnel.avi");
    if (capture == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Can't open video.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (capture == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Can't open video.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    fps = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    no_of_frames = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
    mid_frame = no_of_frames/2;
    omp_set_num_threads(2);


#pragma omp parallel sections
    {
#pragma omp section
    {
        //cvSetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,0);
        IplImage* img = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        cvNamedWindow("Window1",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cvShowImage("Window1",img);
        cvWaitKey(10000);
        cvReleaseImage(&img);
        cvDestroyWindow("Window1");
        cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    }
#pragma omp section
    {
        cvSetCaptureProperty(captureNew,CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,(double)mid_frame-1);
        IplImage* img = cvQueryFrame(captureNew);
        cvNamedWindow("Window2",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cvShowImage("Window2",img);
        cvWaitKey(10000);
        cvReleaseImage(&img);
        cvDestroyWindow("Window2");
        cvReleaseCapture(&captureNew);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: please do not use opencv's deprecated c-api. it is only around for maintaining legacy code.

Comment: What is wrong with my code ??:( @berak

Comment: they stopped developing the c-api in 2010. you can only use ~20% of opencv this way. and anyone, who has to read or maintain your code, will curse you ;)

Comment: I am very much comfortable with java, than any other language. Shall I go ahead with Java API for OpenCV ? @berak

Comment: sure, give it a try at least..

Answer (score 1):

There are several potential problems in the code:

- The most probable cause of is `cvReleaseImage()` being called to free a resource that wasn't created by you. In this case, the `IplImage` was created internally by `cvQueryFrame()`. Doing this can crash your application.
- Print the values of `fps`, `no_of_frames` and `mid_frame` to the screen. The functions that are called to retrieve these values **can fail** and return 0, which would then cause a problem in your application since you pass some of these data to `cvSetCaptureProperty()`.
- Sometimes `cvQueryFrame()` can return `NULL` indicating that there was some problem while retrieving a frame. Passing a `NULL` frame to `cvShowImage()` can also crash your application:

  ```
  IplImage* img = cvQueryFrame(capture);
  if (img == NULL) {
        // handle error
  }
  ```